# How can I acquire an aggregated list of known proxy IP addresses?

Tags: list, proxy

I'd like to use this to help maintain a good defence against people trying to skirt the rules of my system. I've found TOR endpoints, nothing that's readily available to be shot into a script (needs to be parsed) but they work. However I need a list which goes beyond TOR yet I cannot find anything conclusive just yet.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

interesting with tunnel huntering ?  try here.
http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=8Uq&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&ei=6Un0S_KcGYrH-QbFn6GcDg&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CBcQBSgA&q=layer+7+tunneling+detection&spell=1

Answer (score 0):

The better way could be get or **[download fresh proxy IP addresses lists](http://proxy-ip-list.com/download/txt-proxy-list.html)** that users find in internet. Then use that lists as blacklists.

You can periodically parse complete websites with proxy lists and update your blacklists, but there are websites that already provides a way to **[download proxy lists](http://proxy-ip-list.com/download/txt-proxy-list.html)** easily and that lists are updated periodically too. So, the only thing that you need to do is download that proxy list and update yours.